# filtering a column, specify case sensitivity

Tags: python, pandas, case-sensitive

To reduce ambiguity, I want to improve my code to specify that my '==' function can include any case.

For example Apple, APPLE, aPpLe should be accepted (and so on)

```
function = (df.loc[(df['Food']=='Apple') #and so on...
```

Do I have to specify every single variation like below, or is there a cleaner alternative

```
function = (df.loc[(df['Food']=='Apple|apple|APPLE') #and so on...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html#pandas.Series.str.fullmatch) which allows for a `case` argument. `fullmatch` requires the string to be an exact match, not just a substring (for which you would use `.str.contains` or `.str.match`).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Food': ['ApPlE', 'apple', 'APPLE', 'apples', 'Banana']})

# Assign the Boolean mask for illustration
df['any_case_apple'] = df['Food'].str.fullmatch('apple', case=False)
```

---

```
print(df)
#     Food  any_case_apple
#0   ApPlE            True
#1   apple            True
#2   APPLE            True
#3  apples           False
#4  Banana           False
```

Answer (score 4):

To ignore case:

```
df.loc[df['Food'].str.lower()=='apple']

# or

df.loc[df['Food'].str.lower()=='Apple'.lower()]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if `Apple` is *in* any of the strings, ignoring case, you can do this:

```
df[df['Food'].str.contains('apple', case=False)]
```